# Draw polygons in the position of the mouse click

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to draw some polygons in a stack panel. They should be centered where I click with the mouse. They are created, but they are always centered in the middle of the Border Panel, and not where I click. Can someone find the error? (Sorry if there are some italian words, and sorry also for my bad english).

```
public class Prova2 extends Application{
StackPane tavola = new StackPane();
@Override
public void start(Stage stage){
    stage.setTitle("Peace!");
    stage.setHeight(600);
    stage.setWidth(600);

    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

//LEFT
    Label lb = new Label("DRAW");
    VBox container = new VBox();
    final ComboBox disegna = new ComboBox();
    disegna.getItems().addAll(
            "CIRCLE",
            "TRIANGLE",
            "SQUARE");
    disegna.setValue("Choose");
    final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
    TextField input = new TextField("");

    container.getChildren().addAll(lb, disegna, colorPicker, input);

    layout.setLeft(container);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(container, Pos.CENTER);

    //CENTER

    tavola.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
    layout.setCenter(tavola);

    //RIGHT
    Button cancella = new Button("DELETE");
    layout.setRight(cancella);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(cancella, Pos.CENTER);


    //AZIONI COMBOBOX
    tavola.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            double x = arg0.getX();
            double y = arg0.getY();
            System.out.println("X:Y "+x+":"+y+"\n");
            double m;
            if(input.getText().isEmpty()){
                m = 30;
            }
            else{
                m=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
            }
            if(disegna.getValue().equals("CIRCLE")){
                Circle c = new Circle();
                c.setCenterX(x);
                c.setCenterY(y);
                c.setRadius(m);
                c.setOpacity(1);
                c.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
                c.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                tavola.getChildren().add(c);
            }
            if(disegna.getValue().equals("TRIANGLE")){
                Polygon t = new Polygon();
                m=1.73*m;
                t.setLayoutX(x);
                t.setLayoutY(y);
                t.getPoints().add(50.0);
                t.getPoints().add(0.0);
                t.getPoints().add(100.0);
                t.getPoints().add(100.0);
                t.getPoints().add(0.0);
                t.getPoints().add(100.0);
                t.setOpacity(1);
                t.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
                t.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                tavola.getChildren().add(t);
            }
            if(disegna.getValue().equals("SQUARE")){
                m=1.41*m;
                Rectangle q = new Rectangle();
                q.setX(x);
                q.setY(y);
                q.setHeight(m);
                q.setWidth(m);
                q.setOpacity(1);
                q.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
                q.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                tavola.getChildren().add(q);
            }
        }
    });

    cancella.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    tavola.getChildren().removeAll(tavola.getChildren());
                }
    });



    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you are using a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) as DrawPanel. By default a StackPane sets its added elements in the center of the Pane, if the new child could not be sized to fill it as described in the javadoc:

> The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content
>   area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane (either
>   because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it) then it
>   will be aligned within the area using the alignment property, which
>   defaults to Pos.CENTER.

For drawing purposes I usually tend to use an [AnchorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html). You might wonna give it a try unless you have reasons for using a StackPane.